# Properties of the Modulus of Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, continuity, numerical-methods

Let $f \in C^1([a,b]), h>0$, we define the modulus of continuity:

$$
\omega(f;h):=\max_\limits{x,x‘ \in [a,b]: |x-x‘|\leq h} |f(x)-f(x‘)|
$$

I had to show some properties like continuity, monotonicity, sobadditivity… but I‘m stuck with these two: $\omega(f;h) \leq h ||{f‘}||_{\infty}$ and $\omega(|x|^{\alpha};h) \leq C h^{\alpha}$ (with $0<\alpha < 1$, and $a=-1, b=1$).

My attempt, for the first one:

$$
\omega(f;h)= \max_\limits{x \in [a,b-\tilde{h}], \tilde{h} \leq h} |f(x)-f(x+ \tilde{h})|= \max_\limits{x \in [a,b-\tilde{h}], \tilde{h} \leq h} \frac{\tilde{h}}{\tilde{h}} |f(x)-f(x+ \tilde{h})| \leq h\max_\limits{x \in [a,b-\tilde{h}], \tilde{h} \leq h} \frac{|f(x)-f(x+ \tilde{h})|}{\tilde{h}}
$$

Now if I knew that the last expression takes its supremum at $\tilde{h}=0$, I‘d be done, but this doesn‘t have to be the case.

My attempt, for the second one:

$$
\max_\limits{x,x‘ \in [-1,1]: |x-x‘|\leq h} ||x|^{\alpha}-|x‘ |^{\alpha} |= \max_\limits{x,x‘ \in [0,1]: |x-x‘|\leq h} |x ^{\alpha}-x‘^{\alpha} | \leq \dots \leq \max_\limits{x,x‘ \in [0,1]: |x-x‘| \leq h} C|x-x‘|^{\alpha}=ch^{\alpha}
$$

So I‘d have to show $|x ^{\alpha}-x‘^{\alpha} | \leq |x-x‘| ^{\alpha} $, but for some reason I‘m really bad with such inequalities.

I‘d be very happy for some help:)

Comment: The mean value theorem of differentiation is helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $x, y \in [a,b]$, then by the mean value theorem of differentiation there exists at least one $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that
$$ f(x) - f(y) = f'(\xi) (x - y).$$
If $f'$ is continuous, then $\|f'\|_\infty = \sup \{|f'(t)| \: : \: t \in [a,b]\}$ is finite and $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \|f'\|_\infty |x-y|.$$
It follows that $\omega(f; h) \leq \|f'\|_\infty h$.

Now in the special case of $f(x) = |x|^\alpha$ we do not have the required differentiability. I refer you to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/992329/307944) by @jsch that shows that $$||x|^\alpha - |y|^\alpha| \leq ||x|-|y||^\alpha.$$
Since $||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|$ by the triangle inequality and $z \rightarrow |z|^\alpha$ is increasing we have $$||x|^\alpha - |y|^\alpha| \leq |x-y|^\alpha.$$ This exactly the inequality that will allow you to show that $$\omega(x \rightarrow|x|^\alpha,h) \leq h^\alpha.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @HenryT. You are very welcome.